# Stop HTML/Javascript page from loading mid initialization

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html

So imagine a piece of Javascript as the first script on a page along the lines of

```
var MySuperObject = new (function () {
    this.SuperObjectInit();
})();
```

Now imagine that everything that proceeds this script (or a large portion therein) requires the SuperObject to have met its load conditions and loaded correctly.

Assuming for whatever reason the loading of the object fails I need to abort loading the rest of the page and the scripts in particular.

I know the majority of you are going to scream why not have your function issue a callback onSuccess and onFailed but the problem is this is in a ASP.Net project with masterpages, nestedmasterpages, usercontrols and so forth (each of which have their own dependencies and scripts); rendering such an approach problematic.

The other option (I assume) is to use window.location = "myErrorPage.html"; but I dont like the idea of having to create another page for an error message or the fact that it causes a redirect.

What I am hoping to do is something along the lines of

```
StopLoadingPage();
document.write("Error has occurred");
```

But not sure how this might be accomplished.

Comment: What is the superobject?

Comment: Doesn't matter... The key point is handling the error.

Comment: "the problem is this is in a ASP.Net project with masterpages, nestedmasterpages, usercontrols and so forth" this is not a problem. It's client-side, it would be no different if you had used MVC or any other technology like PHP or Java or Coldfusion.

Comment: Please explain? It does matter because how do you handle the OnFailed and OnSuccess events in the child controls? Not to mention - even if there is an easy way to do it - you are talking about rewriting a large amount of code to handle this. It also means that all future pages, controls, masterpages require the OnSuccess OnFailed logic which is another dependency this project just doesnt need.

Comment: Provide a real world problem/example of what you're trying to achieve. 'imagining' is like believing in god. It's hard to imagine something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I have been quite clear regarding both the problem and the reasons why I am looking for this specific approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve isn't how web pages are designed, so as far as I know it is not possible. Logically, you can only stop in Javascript what was started in Javascript, so the only workaround I can think of is to load the dependent scripts asynchronously.

I know this isn't the solution you're looking for, but if there's no other alternative (and I don't think there is), have a look at RequireJS, which handles your JS dependencies for you (no need for callbacks etc...): http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Fair enough... Thank you for your input :-)

Comment: Ended up using window.location = ""; behaves as expected and terminates the loading of the rest of the page but your answer is much appreciated and would be the solution I would use if I started this project from scratch. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Maxim - ah! of course, window.location. I've seen a similar thing done to prevent frame-busting, but didn't occur to me here. Thanks for coming back to post your solution.